# Auto-Py-To-Exe can not convert when trying to install modules

Tags: python, autopy

I use Python 3.10, and whenever i try to convert my file to an exe it gets stuck and gives the error "IndexEroor: Tuple index out of range".
When I remove all imports as numpy, selenium etc. it works fine.
Seems as if I try to import packages it gets stuck.

Comment: please post your code in the dis.py file. There's a issue on python 3.10 that was supposed to be fixed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.